# POS Testing manual and automation

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-design

All,

I am new to POS testing.I absolutely have no clue on where to start and how to choose an automation tool for POS. We are using XPIENT POS. I have been going to through most of the topics in the forum on POS testing and i was able to find inputs on scenarios for cashier activity,credit card and performance.
Experts please throw some light in this area for me to set up a POS testing base.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This is a site for specific questions.  Do you have a specific question, or are you just looking for any arbitrary information we might have about POS testing?

Comment: Seems like he is asking for complete guidance for testing POS. He wants to know how to start testing from scratch..